# Why is the default middleware order config commented out by default in SailsJS?

Tags: sails.js

I tried adding a custom middleware (express-useragent). I put this in the middleware object in http.js:

```
useragent: require('express-useragent').express()
```

But it didn't work. I read that I need to uncomment the `order` array, and that my custom middleware will run wherever the `'$custom'` entry is in that array. I did this but still my custom middleware was not invoked. Then I replaced the `'myRequestLogger'` with my middleware, like this:

```
order: [
      'startRequestTimer',
      'cookieParser',
      'session',
      'useragent', //'myRequestLogger',
      'bodyParser',
      'handleBodyParserError',
      'compress',
      'methodOverride',
      'poweredBy',
      '$custom',
      'router',
      'www',
      'favicon',
      '404',
      '500'
    ],
```

now it works but I am not sure if this is the correct order I should use. Is there a reason why the order array is commented out? Why can't it just work after adding the custom middleware to the object. It's very confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything that is commented out in the sails config is actually the default. I guess they decided to do it that way so it's easier to see what parts are altered...

Regarding your second question, as far as I know, you have to add it to the order array to specify when the middleware should be used. After all the order does make a difference. Sails will start at the top and work itself one middleware layer to the next one for each request.